# How to make tile turnaround animation for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am making a memory type game on iPhone, I would like to know what would be the best way to make an animation of tile turning around to reveal what is on the other side.

So user would tap a tile and animation would start turning the tile around.

Thanx for suggestions
Ladislav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use **UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight** it sounds perfect

Comment: Hey, but is that for the whole screen, or can it be used just for a single tile. Since there are for example 8 tiles on screen, and just one needs to be flipped

Comment: it can be used on a per-view basis